# Get multiple IIS websites .Net CLR version via powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, iis, server, scripting

I am trying to get the .Net CLR version of each application pool with their respective virtual directories.

I have the below script which returns the website and its app pool with no issues, however I can't figure out how to use the "Get-IISAppPool" in the below snippet for me to return it's .Net CLR version as well.

```
$Websites = Get-IISSite "mylocalsite" #if we want to specify only 1 website 

$AllVDirs = @()

foreach($Site in $Websites)
{
    $VDirs = Get-WebApplication -Site $Site.Name
    foreach($webvdirectory in $VDirs)
    {
            $vdir = New-Object psobject -Property @{
                "Name" = ($webvdirectory.path -split "/")[-1]
                "Site" = $Site.name
                "Path" = $webvdirectory.path
                "App Pools" = $webvdirectory.applicationPool
                "Physical Path" = $webvdirectory.physicalPath
                #"PhysicalPathCredentials" = $webvdirectory.userName
            }

            $AllVDirs += $vdir
    } 
}

$AllVDirs
```

Comment: If you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis, you will see this question itself is invalid. You can only check .NET CLR version for application pools (and the IIS applications hosted in each pools), not for sites.

Comment: If you want to get the site .net CLR version, the best way is using `Environment.Version Property` to in code. It is not get through powershell.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.version?view=net-6.0

Comment: You want to call [`Get-IISAppPool $webvdirectory.applicationPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/get-iisapppool?view=windowsserver2022-ps)